# C# string search

Tags: c#, string

[image]I have string which contain white space like

```
string str="Option (A) and option (   B   ) and (c     )"
```

If and i want to search `(A)` `(B)` `(C)` position and length I know I can use `string.replace(" ","")` and search.

Here I know `(B)` is there but due to white space I am not able to get correct Index and Length .

For example in this case I want `str.IndexOf("(B)",0)` should return 22(I calculated manually). and also get length I mean my program should know here `(B)` start index=22 and length=9 (here length of `(B)` is not 3 because in string due to white space its increase to 9.

Thanks

Comment: Why exactly can't you use `str.replace`?

Comment: i have to use that index for further in non edited string .. If i will use str.replace it will not give correct index

Comment: You might want to try regular expressions that allow you to search for optional whitespace something like `\(\w*B\w*\)`.

Comment: what will be the values inside the brackets? one letter?

Comment: @Nino no it may be one or more than one character and any number of white space may come

Answer (score 3):

Use a regex for this:

```
var str = "Option (A) and option (   B   ) and (c     )";
var matches = Regex.Matches(str, @"\([^()]*\)");
foreach (Match match in matches) {
    Console.WriteLine("Value: {0}", match.Value);
    Console.WriteLine("Position: {0}",match.Index);
    Console.WriteLine("Length: {0}",match.Length);
}
```

See the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/xtFUG7)

A [**`Match`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match(v=vs.110).aspx) object has the necessary [**`Index`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.capture.index(v=vs.110).aspx) and [**`Length`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.capture.length(v=vs.110).aspx) properties you may access after getting all the matches.

The pattern here matches:

- `\(` - a literal `(`
- `[^()]*` - zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a literal `)`.

You may adjust it say, to match `(`, 0+ whitespaces, a letter, zero or more whitespaces and a `)` by using `@"\(\s*\p{L}\s*\)"`.

Comment: Everything is fine but what if we want to search some string(it may be (A) or any other string foo) in other string str ?

Comment: @Ajeet: The current question does not really contain the requirements for what there must appear inside parentheses, that is why I suggested a rather generic pattern. The pattern can be adjusted more or less easily, but the requirements should be provided first.

Comment: So, you just need `@"\([\sa-zA-Z]*\)"`, right? Whitespace or letter symbols only inside parentheses?